# Journal inserts errors into paper then ignore corrections at proof stage. What should I do?

Tags: publications

A paper was accepted by an Elsevier jounral and when I recieved the proofs they had inserted a large number of errors throughout the paper. The errors weren't significant but it makes the paper look sloppy. I pointed these errors out at the proof stage and assumed they would be fixed. When the "online first" article was posted the errors remained. Have contacted the journal manager but they have taken no action. What should I do?

Comment: You should escalate? Elsevier has a hierarchy of editors.

Comment: @DimitriVulis, why not make it an answer?

Comment: *they have taken no action* Did they acknowledge receipt and then took no action? If so did they explain why?